# Moq setting up ServiceLocator

Tags: c#, .net, moq

I'm trying to set up service locator for unit testing like so:

```
var mockS = new Mock<IServiceLocator>();
ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider(() => mockS.Object);
mockS.Setup(x => x.GetInstance<IObjectFactoryMethod<IAddress>>()).Returns(new Mock<ObjectsFactory>().Object);

var factoryMock = new Mock<IObjectFactoryMethod<IAddress>>(MockBehavior.Strict);
factoryMock.Setup(x => x.Create(null)).Returns(new Mock<IAddress>());

var factory = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<IObjectFactoryMethod<IAddress>>();

// testing - factory returns null
var address = factory.Create(null); // address is null
```

Code executes fine. factory shows as mocked factory during debugging, however when Create(null) is called it returns null instead of new IAddress mock.

Comment: Your "create" appears to be being setup on an object you aren't using.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
var mockS = new Mock<IServiceLocator>();
ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider(() => mockS.Object);

var factoryMock = new Mock<IObjectFactoryMethod<IAddress>>(MockBehavior.Strict);
factoryMock.Setup(x => x.Create(null)).Returns(new Mock<IAddress>().Object);

mockS.Setup(x => x.GetInstance<IObjectFactoryMethod<IAddress>>()).Returns(factoryMock.Object);

var factory = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<IObjectFactoryMethod<IAddress>>();

// testing - factory returns null
var address = factory.Create(null); // address is null
```

Comment: factoryMock => should be factoryMock.Object, and new Mock<IAddress>() => should be: new Mock<IAddress>().Object

Comment: I'll fix the answer accordingly, thanks. I haven't got a rev environment to try it in

Comment: I believe there is a SetupProperty method on the Mock object which you use in a similar way to setting up methods.